# Is there a well maintained docker image with gcloud installed in it?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gitlab

I'm setting up GitLab to build a Docker image and push it to Google Cloud Platform. Currently I'm doing this using the `docker:stable-git` image (no particular reason other than I've seen it in some tutorial/docs). One set of actions that I'm doing in every run is installing the Google Cloud SDK, gcloud.

Is there a well maintained Docker image I should use instead of `docker:stable-git` that already comes with a recent/latest version of gcloud I could use instead? It'd be great to save some GitLab execution time.

Comment: This clearly falls into the "asks us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" category of off-topic questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google maintains and has published a google/cloud-sdk docker image which is based off Debian and includes the default command line tools of Google Cloud SDK - you can find it on docker hub here: https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/

You can pull it from docker hub with the following:

`docker pull google/cloud-sdk:latest`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21358434)

Comment: Good point - I've updated the answer to include more detail and reference the link rather than depend on it.

Comment: I'm sorry for your downvotes. Your answer was exactly what I was after and really helped me. I also think it's a canonical answer because it's coming from the same source as gcloud itself, so, it's not an opinion or recommendation.

Comment: No worries - glad it's what you were looking for!